# How to horizontally align the bullets to the left when removing padding from the ul?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have the following code :

```html
<p>Get ready.</p>

<ul>
  <li>This</li>
  <li>is</li>
  <li>not</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>list.</li>
</ul>
```

I'd like to remove the left padding of the ul so that the bullets are horizontally aligned with the text that comes before the ul. Unfortunately, when I set the left padding of the ul to 0px, the content of the li's is aligned with what's above them, and the bullets stick out to the left. 
I could manually set the padding of the ul to a value that works in my current browser, but I'm afraid it might not work in all browsers.

Comment: `list-style-position: inside;`

Comment: Thanks @TemaniAfif, this solved my problem. If you'd like to write a short answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I am searching for the duplicate, I am pretty sure I saw one before.

Comment: can you show us your expected result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
<p>Get ready.</p>

<ul style="padding-left: 0;list-style-position: inside;"> <li>This</li>
<li>is</li>
  <li>not</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>list.</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: hope this helps!

Answer (score -4):

```
ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px
}
```

this should do it.